# Why does Mozilla consider Conditional catch-blocks non-standard?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, adonis.js

I read here in [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) a docs saying the try...catch conditional is

> "non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on
>   production"

but i don't understand why.

And I want to know How can I make this statement in a situation where I can create multiple response.status for each situation. For example, this is my code now

```
    class BookController {
  async store ({ request, response }) {
    try {
      const values = { ...request.all(), user_id: request.user_id }

      const validatedValues = await importValidate.validate(values, rules, messages)
      return Book.create(validatedValues)
    } catch (e) {
      response.status(409).json(e)
    }
  }
```

And i need it to be multiples response.status to each situation, for each response based in my rules.

I'm currently using JS, Node, Adonis and in this validation process, [Indicative](https://indicative.adonisjs.com/)/Validator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation you read already explains:

> **Non-standard**
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

In such a case it would be better for you to define your own conditional statements

instead of

```
try {
    myroutine(); // may throw three types of exceptions
} catch (e if e instanceof TypeError) {
    // statements to handle TypeError exceptions
} catch (e if e instanceof RangeError) {
    // statements to handle RangeError exceptions
} catch (e if e instanceof EvalError) {
    // statements to handle EvalError exceptions
} catch (e) {
    // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
    logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
}
```

use

```
try {
    myroutine(); // may throw three types of exceptions
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof TypeError) {
        // statements to handle TypeError exceptions
    } else if (e instanceof RangeError) {
        // statements to handle RangeError exceptions
    } else if (e instanceof EvalError) {
        // statements to handle EvalError exceptions
    } else {
        // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
        logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
    }
}
```

In this way you will still separately handle all the exceptions, but within a single catch statement

Comment: I cannot use this statemente "instanceof" because ```e```  return ```[
  {
    message: 'code está com o tipo incorreto! (integer)',
    validation: 'integer',
    field: 'code'
  }
]
```
So i can not use "TypeError, RangeError, EvalError" because they dont return a valid boolean. Maybe has a way to do this correct, but i am very new in this world and i cant find how to do this, i accept sugestions :D

Comment: then just write your own checks, if e returns an array of objects, conditional catch blocks wouldnt help you anyway